# Unlocking Bootloader Android 7.1.2

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock

I have a RCA device running Android 7.1.2. I'm having difficulty unlocking the bootloader.

On my device I've an option to turn on `OEM Unlocking`. When I try it asks if I want to enable when I select `Enable` it just jumps back to off position.

This is what I have tried.
adb reboot fastboot
The device reboots and stays on the splash screen when I do fastboot devices it shows "0123456789 fastboot". This seems weird to me I expected to see the S/N number like I see when I do adb devices.
Then I tried "fastboot flashing unlock" I don't see any change on the device and I instantly get FAILED.

[image: Fastboot Unlocking]

How can I get the bootloader unlocked?

I have seen people that have gotten it unlocked, but they were on a previous version of Android.

My tablets info:

- Model: **RCT6973W43R**
- Android Version: **7.1.2**
- Android Security Patch: **October 1, 2018**
- Kernel Version: **3.10.104 Fri Oct 19 11:05:52 CST 2018**
- Build number: **RCT6973W43R-ANDROID7.1-V38-V1.16.132-DS-E17**
- Rockship: **RK3066**

Answer (score 2):

**Enable OEM Unlocking**
If your devices manufacturer allows OEM unlocking
A.K.A (Also Known As) "Bootloader Unlocking".

[image: DevOpt]

[image: OEMUnlock]

[image: Enable Unlock]

After Enabling OEM Unlocking

- Reboot to Fastboot

  ADB

  - `adb reboot bootloader`
- OEM Unlock

  - `fastboot oem unlock`
    or
    `fastboot oem unlock -go`
    or
    `fastboot oem unlock /path/to/unlock-token.bin`

If you have an MTK CPU you might be interested in flashing image's using a scatter file and SP Flash Tool v5.16 or above, as it doesn't require an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. As mentioned in my question I already tried to enable the OEM Unlocking in the Developer Options. When I try it just slides right back to the off position.

Comment: You've had a Kernel update alongside the system update... I'm fairly sure that the new kernel locks out modifications and bootloader unlocking.   ... As it has an Intel CPU you can use https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-intel-phone-flash-tool ... Try looking around and getting familiar with stock firmware flashing on your device... This is using USB access to the CPU and bypasses androids security regarding bootloader unlocking... same for MTK CPUs etc...

Comment: Can you advise me where I can get more info on this flashing I wasn't successful or at least I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: I searched Intel ( Your CPU ) Firmware flashing, and it gave me that software, ... this tells me that you can access your system via the CPU in a "PreBoot" state, bypassing the System protection features... It's the same for MTK Mediatek CPU's, I'm more familiar with MTKs.

Comment: I have used the Wwr Tool in the past for getting the ROM on a MTK device. I had a tutorial from Hovatek Forums that helped me (https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html). Would you know if there is any similar tutorial or at least some guide for a similar thing for the Intel chipset?

Comment: All I can see is that this tool is used to FLASH a ROM. I'm looking for something that can download the ROM fist. Is there any tool out there that does that?

Comment: Are you trying to compile a stock firmware ?  or unlock the bootloader ?    This is the guide I found for unlocking the bootloader and getting root https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/guide-rca-voyager-rct6873w42-unlock-t3582973  ... But I'm not sure what you want to do   ..... If you have a copy of the stock boot.img and recovery.img, you can compile the CWM image's with them to remove CWM and replace the images with stock recovery... Then you'd have a stock firmware, but a device that has CWM Recovery, you then flash the stock recovery, or compiled stock firmware, and you stock.

Comment: I'm trying to download the images from the device. I can't unlock the bootloader as per the original question (the OEM unlock setting just jumps back to off). On a Mediatek device I was able to download the images (the full ROM actually) without unlocking the bootloader. You mentioned that this is possible with the Intel Flash Toll, but I can't figure out how. So I'm asking if there is any guide that I can refer to to help me with this. Or if there is any other way to achieve this goal.